# Importing variables from components, benefit?

Tags: css, sass

First some background. We have a main sass file `main.scss` where we are basically just importing other scss files.

```
/* ==========================================================================
                                    Base
   ========================================================================== */

@import "base/colors";
@import "base/variables";
@import "base/typography";
@import "base/layout";
@import "base/font-icons";
@import "base/base";
@import "base/ie-fixes";
```

Later we import components too from outside of the `styles` folder because we have a components like development approach where we have components with it's .js .html .scss files "bundled" in a folder.

Now the question. Say I have such a component e.g `/account`. In `account.scss` I am using variables from `styles/base/variables` if I write the `account.scss` file with `@import "../../styles/base/variables"` then I am duplicating code for the sass output IF i have other rules defined in the variables.scss and NOT only true variable declarations. Okay, in variables.scss I should only have variables but say in `colors.scss` I may have variable declarations as well as rule declarations e.g

```
$grey: grey;
.grey { color: $grey; }
```

Now if I import colors my output sass file will contain .grey { .. } at least two times so it is duplicated. Okay, let's split colors up and move rules into a different file and let variables declarations only. Then I can freely import the file without duplication.

Now my question is why would I import? Is there any benefit of importing variable decalarions into `account.scss` outside of documentation?

I hope I was clear I tried to be as clear as I could.

Answer (score 0):

You already answered your own question:

> Okay, let's split colors up and move rules into a different file and
>   let variables declarations only. Then I can freely import the file
>   without duplication.

I would always separate `mixins` from `functions` from `variables` – and most important: separate all of these from output that is being generated. This way you can safely import modules or single parts of your SCSS anywhere.

**For example:**

```
/setup
    _variables.scss
    _functions.scss
    _mixins.scss
    ...
    _module.scss
/global
    _base.scss
    _layout.scss
    _typography.scss
    _helpers.scss
    ...
    _module.scss
/components
    _slideshow.scss
    _pagination.scss
    _widgets.scss
    ...
    _module.scss

main.scss
```

Every `_module.scss` in one of the subfolders would like like this:

```
/* setup/_modules.scss */
@import 'variables';
@import 'functions';
@import 'mixins';
```

The `main.scss` would look like this:

```
/* main.scss */
@import 'setup/module';
@import 'global/module';
@import 'components/module';
```

Your question after what would be the benefit of importing: I don’t know. You have to know since only you know your application. If a 'standalone' component uses the same color set, for example, importing one single `_colors.scss` is indeed a good idea and keeps you DRY.

Comment: Thanks, but what are the benefits of importing `@import 'variables';` in every module if theoretically after the first module imported in main.scss everything is there. I mean if you'd write `@import 'variables';` as the first line in `main.scss` then you don't need to import it anywhere else.

Comment: This can, of course, make sense. If a component should work standalone, but is also a part of the main application, for example. Check [compass-import-once](https://rubygems.org/gems/compass-import-once/versions/1.0.5), which will prevent a file from `@import` twice.